# Add another table to mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

so far I have the following SQL query which works great:

```sql
SELECT *,
  MATCH(title, content_plain_text) AGAINST ('$searchTerm') AS score, 
  (MATCH(title, content_plain_text) AGAINST ('$searchTerm') / maxScore) AS normalisedScore
FROM pages,
  (SELECT MAX(MATCH(title, content_plain_text) AGAINST ('$searchTerm')) AS maxScore 
    FROM pages) maxScoreTable
    WHERE MATCH(title, content_plain_text) AGAINST ('$searchTerm')
    AND active = 1
    ORDER BY score DESC
```

So now I want to search another table with the same field names too, how do I go about that whilst keeping the ranking etc?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could use a `union` to create a view of your two tables and use the view in your query as you would have done with `pages`

Comment: You should really explain what you mean rather more clearly.  For example, you should give this other table a name - otherwise, everyone (anyone) answering has to invent a name for it.  It never does any harm to give the relevant subset of the columns in the table explicitly; as it is, we have to work out that the `Pages` table has columns `Title`, `Content_Plain_Text` and `Active`.  You said the other tables has the same columns?  The maximum ranking is across both tables.  Do you really need the normalized score from the query?  Your reporting tool should be able to do that.

Comment: @bbeckford: Is your problem solved? Please elaborate more on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just `union all` your `pages` table with the other table (lets assume its called `more_pages`).

The `WITH` construct really fits such problems well, but unfortunately MySQL does not support it yet.
The most elegant alternative I could come up with would be to create a view to encapsulate this union:

```
CREATE VIEW all_pages AS
SELECT * FROM pages
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM more_pages


SELECT *,
  MATCH(title, content_plain_text) AGAINST ('$searchTerm') AS score, 
  (MATCH(title, content_plain_text) AGAINST ('$searchTerm') / maxScore) AS normalisedScore
FROM all_pages,
  (SELECT MAX(MATCH(title, content_plain_text) AGAINST ('$searchTerm')) AS maxScore 
    FROM all_pages) maxScoreTable
    WHERE MATCH(title, content_plain_text) AGAINST ('$searchTerm')
    AND active = 1
    ORDER BY score DESC
```